# Random class does not create random number?

Tags: c#, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Random class isn't really random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514101/why-is-random-class-isnt-really-random)

I have following kind of code:

```
public static int GenerateRandomNumber(int seed)
{
    var random = new Random(seed);                
    int num = random.Next();
    while(num.ToString().Length != 6){
        num = random.Next();
    }
    return num;
}
```

I want to get different number every time when call this function even with same seed. But I always got same result. 
For example, every time when call `GenerateRandomNumber(1)`, I always got number 640839.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Really bad way to create 6-digit random number. Use `Next(100000,1000000)` instead

Comment: `Random.Next()` is an overloaded. [You can pass in two integers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) to specify the range in which the returned number should be within.

Comment: what is the length 6 relevant? Do you really plan on looping?

Comment: Your code is highly inefficient. If you want a 6 digit number, you can use `random.Next(100000,1000000)` which will always generate a number that is six digits. Also, if you want to ensure your number is six digits, don't convert it to string and check the length. Instead test that it's value is between 100000 and 999999.

Answer (score 12):

> I want to get different number every time when call this function even with same seed.

Since that is the *opposite* of [what the Random constructor is documented to do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329890%28VS.71%29.aspx), you are going to have to learn to live with disappointment. You can't always get what you want.

Answer (score 6):

Here is your problem:

```
var random = new Random(id);
```

`Random` generates a pseudo-random set of results - for the same seed, you would get the same sequence every time.

Change the creation of the `Random` object to a static field and you will get a different result whenever you call it.

From MSDN - [Random Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx):

> The random number generation starts from a seed value. If the same seed is used repeatedly, the same series of numbers is generated.

Answer (score 0):

`Random` creates a series of pseudo-random numbers based on an initial value called a seed (`id` in your code).

Since the seed is identical then all calls to the function will follow the same code-path and generate the same result.

Make the `random = new Random(seed)` a static variable in your function or make it a member in the containing class and pass it to all functions/classes that need it.

Consider using a time based seed value when you are done developing the program.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get different number every time when call this function even with same seed.

That's not how seeds work. The whole point of a seed is that using the same seed will result in the same series of pseudo-random numbers. The series is deterministic

Answer (score 0):

The problem you need to fix is to align your expectations with the [product specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx):

> Providing an identical seed value to
>   different Random objects causes each
>   instance to produce identical
>   sequences of random numbers.

So either expect the same sequence froma  seed, or don't use a seed.